# RegExp Weirdness in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable string in my JavaScript code containing a comma delimited list of words and or phrases, for example:

String 1  : “abc, def  hij,  klm”

String 2  : “abc, def”

I want to insert  the word ‘and’ after the last comma in the string to get

String 1  : “abc, def  hij, and klm”

String 2  : “abc, and def”

I put together the following code:

```
// replace the last comma in the list with  ", and"  
var regEx1 = new RegExp(",(?=[A-z ]*$)" )      
var commaDelimList = commaDelimList.replace(regEx1, ", and ");
```

The problem is that it does not work if the comma delimited string has only two items separated by one comma.

So the results of the above example are

String 1  : ”abc, def  hij, and klm”

String 2  : “abc, def”

Why is the RegExp not working and what can I use to get the result I want?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2w723/

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is this really exactly what you're doing, or have you simplified something along the way? Also, don't use `[A-z]`, it matches more than you think. `(?i)[A-Z]` or `[A-Za-z]` is better if you want to match an ASCII letter.

Comment: @Tim - Where can I lookup the diff between [A-z] and [A-Za-z]? And yes, it was an oversimplification. I have upvoted your comment.

Comment: Oh, that's easy. Look at any ASCII table. You'll see that between `Z` and `a`, there are the characters `[\]^_` and also the backtick: `

Comment: Ditto what Tim said (your code above works fine). But instead of: `[A-z ]*`, I would use: `[^,]*` _"Zero or more non-commas."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure a regex was the right way to go there...

Why not use [LastIndexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) and replace that with your string?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a relatively straight forward task, a little string manipulation may be beneficial - you'll realize better performance too.

```
var str = 'abc, def, hij, klm',
    index = str.lastIndexOf(','),
    JOINER = ', and';

//'abc, def, hij, and klm'
str.slice(0, index) + JOINER + str.slice(index+1);
```

Comment: Only slightly.  Someone once tried to convince me it was terrible to use regex for such small tasks... but I still do!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried you one but this works

```
'abc, def'.replace( /,(?=[A-z ]*$)/, ", and" )
```